# Store DataType<? extends T> in a class field

Tags: java, android, generics, httpclient

I am trying to store a variable with the data type `DataType<? extends T>`.
I have tried with `DataType<? extends T> var;` but it seems not to work.

Storing as `DataType<?> var;` works, but I can't cast to `DataType<? extends T>`.

Is there any possibility to get it working?

**EDIT:**

Perhaps it will be easier, when I give more information.

I use the *AndroidHttpClient* in an *AsyncTask*, which executes different requests in background while showing a *ProgressDialog*.
I am looking for a simple implementation, which may allow me to transfer *ResponseHandler* as parameters for the method [execute](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html#execute%28org.apache.http.HttpHost,%20org.apache.http.HttpRequest%29) of the [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) implementation.

Comment: Can you add some code containing the datamember declaration, as well as the class generic declaration?

Comment: This is the [Interface](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/ResponseHandler.html) and this is the [method](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html#execute%28org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest,%20org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler%29)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

The problem is the parameterized type is declared in the method. You cannot store the parameter with the types you want as a class data member, because there is no way to know the type in the class declaration, because the type information is only determined when the method is called.

```
public class Snippet<T> {

    private final ResponseHandler<? extends T> var;

    public Snippet(ResponseHandler<? extends T> var) {
        super();
        this.var = var;
    }


    public <U> U execute(ResponseHandler<? extends U> responseHandler) {
        // This class is generic wrt to T, but this method is generice wrt to U.
        // You cannot store the variable passed in here in a data member
        // because the type cannot possible be known at compile time, as it
        // depends on client code calling this method.
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice snippet but I don't know T. See my comment above.

Comment: @H3llGhost That is _exactly_ the problem. You don't/can't know T (or U in my example), so there is no way to maintain a handle on it while maintaining type information. So you have to fall back to <?>. I'm still 100% not clear on what you really want to do, but I have the suspicion that it is not possible.

Comment: `<?>` doesn't work because the method `execute(HttpHost target, HttpRequest request, ResponseHandler<? extends T> responseHandler)` needs the *ResponseHandler* with `<? extends T>`.